# How to check if the radio button is selected or not in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="selectCard_left">
<input id="26110162" class="default_shipping_address" type="radio" name="address" checked="true">
<span>Seleccionar como tarjeta predeterminada</span>
```

I am trying with `driver.findElement(By.id("17390233")).isSelected();`, but I am not getting any value.

Comment: The ID doesnt match. If is autogenerated maybe you should use the name or class field.

Comment: here we have checked="true"> i want to check that whether the radio button checked or not can you please tell me how to write the code

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("26110162")).isSelected();

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("26110162")).isSelected();
```

or

```
String str = driver.findElement(By.id("26110162")).getAttribute("checked");
if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
{
    System.out.println("Checkbox selected");
}
```

if the ID is changing...
use the following XPATH:

```
//input[span='Seleccionar como tarjeta predeterminada']
```

or

```
//input[@name='address' and @type='radio']
```

Answer (score 1):

`.isSelected()` function will returns you a boolean value `True` or `False`, depending on that you can check the condition and enable or leave the radio button selected.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='26110162']")).isSelected().
```

Declare a boolean value and store the result then provide an if condition to validate

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of this method:-

1. `selenium.isChecked(Locator);`
2. `List<WebElement> radio = driver.findElements(By.name("address"));
   radio.get(0).getAttribute("checked"));`

Hope it will help...